# How do I run 2 environments of SkyDns/Skydock simultaneously?

Tags: docker, skydns, skydock

Ref: https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock
https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydns

First I fired up those two instances.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 172.17.42.1:53:53/udp --name skydns crosbymichael/skydns -nameserver 8.8.8.8:53 -domain docker

docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock --name skydock crosbymichael/skydock -ttl 30 -environment dev -s   /docker.sock -domain docker -name skydns
```

And this setup is working as expected.

Now I want to spawn another production environment. This time I only fired another skydock container with the env production as follows.

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock --name skydock-prod crosbymichael/skydock -ttl 30 -environment prod -s /docker.sock -domain docker -name skydns
```

Querying the api doesn't show the production skydoc.

```
curl $(docker-ip):8080/skydns/services/
```

And now I am wondering on how to setup the production version of skydock.

Do I have to run in separate docker-host?
If I fire up in the same docker host, in which DNS url entry will the new containers be available?
Do I have to pass some flags/variables when I fire new containers to be available in the production env?

Answer (score 4):

I don't about the way to make 2 or more skydock instances listen to the same docker.sock (within single host machine). I think conceptually it is not right. Docker containers know nothing about your logical enviroments (production, staging, ...)

I got a multihost setup with skydns and skydock. I run skydns on a separate host. Each of two other servers run single instance of skydock, which registers all docker containers ips in centralised SkyDNS, so that all containers are visible by dns name across different physical hosts.

All of that is working on top of Flannel network overlay https://github.com/coreos/flannel (which requires etcd)

Comment: This makes sense. @viktortnk Have you any notes/posts of those commands to setup skydns in separate host and such as you've described anywhere? It would be more helpful.

Comment: How are you binding docker to dns and flannel?

Comment: /usr/bin/docker -d --bip=${FLANNEL_SUBNET} --mtu=${FLANNEL_MTU}. I'd recommend looking at this repo for config files examples https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-fleet-tutorial

Comment: For the SkyDNS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw42q1ofrV0. docker run -d --name skydns -p 53:53/udp -p 8080:8080/tcp crosbymichael/skydns:latest -nameserver="8.8.8.8:53" -domain="cluster.whisk.com" <br/> Then on each node with skydock: <br/> docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock --name skydock crosbymichael/skydock -ttl 30 -environment dev -s /docker.sock -domain cluster.whisk.com -skydns="http://SKYDNS_IP_ADDRESS:8080"